# Unrecognized expression '$regex inside $project

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hi im try to group all elements by _id, that will it same in all cases

```
db.movies.aggregate([
{
    $project:{
        _id:{
            award:{$cond:[
                {$and:[{awards:{$regex:/win/}}]}
                ]}
        },
    imdb:1
    }
},
{
    $group:{
        highest_rating:{$max:'$imdb.rating'},
        lowest_rating:{$min:'$imdb.rating'},
        average_rating:{$avg:'$imdb.rating'},
        deviation:{$stdDevPop:'$imdb.rating'}
    }
}
])
```

But the response its

```
{
"message" : "Unrecognized expression '$regex'",
"operationTime" : "Timestamp(1560994467, 1)",
"ok" : 0,
"code" : 168,
"codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator",
"$clusterTime" : {
    "clusterTime" : "Timestamp(1560994467, 1)",
    "signature" : {
        "hash" : "++GYj/cVU+Xk2bYmDYAowZfrhWw=",
        "keyId" : "6661714504839069697"
    }
},
"name" : "MongoError"
```

}
What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use $regex inside $cond. There's an issue in Jira with this specific issue you can see it here: 
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8892

Answer (score 2):

For people who found this (like me), the issue was corrected in May/2019 (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947) and you should use `$regexMatch` instead

```
db.coll.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        region: {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    $regexMatch: {
                        input: “$phoneNumber”,
                        regex: “^212.*$”,
                    }               
                }
                 then: "New York",
                else: "Somewhere Else"
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Answer (score -1):

In group $regex its not allowed, i change my query from $regex inside $group to $match

```
 db.movies.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { awards: { $exists: true } },
        { awards: { $regex: /Won/ } },
        {
          $or: [
            { awards: { $regex: /Oscar/ } },
            { awards: { $regex: /Oscars/ } }

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      exists: 1,
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$exists",
      highest_rating: { $max: '$imdb.rating' },
      lowest_rating: { $min: '$imdb.rating' },
      average_rating: { $avg: '$imdb.rating' },
      deviation: { $stdDevPop: '$imdb.rating' }
    }
  }
])
```